# SQL difficult JOIN tables

Tags: sql

Suppose I write a query that finds the names of all artists which have members who were not born in the 1960s and another query to find the names of all artists which do not have any members born in the 1960s.

So we are speaking of these three tables:

### Artists

```
ArtistID, ArtistName, Region, EntryDate
```

### Members

```
MemberId, Firstname, Lastname, Birthday
```

The relationship between the Aritsts and Members Tables is the XrefArtistsMembers table:

### XrefArtistsMembers

```
MemberId, ArtistID, RespParty
```

I've started the Query with:

```
select salesid, firstname, lastname, birthday 
from members 
where year(birthday) >= 1970 or year(birthday) < 1960;
```

But what would be true of any artist that appeared in the results of the first query but not in the results of the second?

Comment: What's the relationship between the `artists` and `members` tables?

Comment: `artists which have members` => I can't seem to find that in your tables. Also where did `salesid` come from?

Comment: You would need a relationship between the tables as stated and I would suggest checking into using between instead of operators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question seems not to be looking for code. The question is:

> But what would be true of any artist that appeared in the results of the first query but not in the results of the second?

So, the first query gets all artists with SOME members not born in 1960. The second query gets all artists WITH NO member born in 1960. Hence, what you can be sure of is that the artists returned in the first query have SOME BUT NOT ALL members (not) born in 1960.

Answer (score 0):

Each can be done with an IN or NOT IN condition:

```
-- Artists with NO members born in the 60s

SELECT * FROM Artists
WHERE ArtistID NOT IN (
    SELECT ArtistID 
    FROM XrefArtistsMembers x
    INNER JOIN Members m ON x.MemberId = m.MemberID
    WHERE year(birthday) BETWEEN 1960 AND 1969)

-- Artists with ANY member NOT born in the 60s

SELECT * FROM Artists
WHERE ArtistID IN (
    SELECT ArtistID 
     FROM XrefArtistsMembers x
    INNER JOIN Members m ON x.MemberId = m.MemberID
    WHERE year(birthday) NOT BETWEEN 1960 AND 1969
)
```

Comment: I try to avoid `IN (subquery)` with MySQL, it usually optimizes it very poorly. JOINs are better.

Comment: @Barmar No one mentioned MySql, but in MySQl an IN performs worse that a JOIN where you need to remove duplicates?

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice that he didn't specify the DBMS. The problem with MySQL is that it usually uses the wrong index when you do `IN (subquery)`. It does a full scan of the main table and matches against the index of the table in the subquery.

Comment: The table had multiple spellings in the OP. I updated it to use the correctly spelled one everywhere: XrefArtistsMembers

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of Artists that have members born outside the 60's with:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ArtistName
FROM Artists a
JOIN XRefArtistsMembers am ON a.ArtistID = am.ArtistID
JOIN Member m ON m.MemberID = am.MemberID
WHERE YEAR(m.birthday) NOT BETWEEN 1960 and 1969;
```

To get Artists that have *no* members born in the 60's:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ArtistName
FROM Artists a
LEFT JOIN XrefArtistsMembers am ON a.ArtistID = am.ArtistID
LEFT JOIN Member m ON m.MemberID = am.MemberID AND YEAR(m.birthday) BETWEEN 1960 and 1969
WHERE m.MemberID IS NULL
```